# Geometry nodes face count per instances

Tags: modeling, geometry-nodes

I'm trying to make a geometry node setup that displays the face count of each object of a collection, but I can get it to retrieve the count for each individual objects (it only displays the total). Is there a way to do this? I tried using the mesh island node without much succes unfortuanetly
[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm very sorry for you, but this doesn't work structurally the way you set it up. First, the node `Attribute Statistic` always returns a value that refers to the whole geometry (you would have to work with `Accumulate Field` instead), and second, the instances will always look the same, because an instance is a duplicate of an object. You would have to create and position the numbers dynamically instead.

Comment: I see, I had a feeling I wasn't doing it the right way

Comment: Hi, @quellenform.. can you think of a clean way of storing number of  (realized) faces per instance on original instances? the only way I've found is a scale-to-0 and merge hack.. maybe I should post this q  as one of my own.

Comment: @RobinBetts ...maybe this one? https://i.stack.imgur.com/EyHw3.png

Comment: @quellenform .. OK,  a bit less grubby than mine :) (I scaled realized instances to merged points and sampled those) I thought there might be a many-to-one indexing trick I hadn't grasped.. it's reassuring your method is similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is now possible to get the face count of each instance using the repeat zone

[image]